# Magento2 : Display Bestselling products for last 7 days

Tags: magento2, product, best-seller

I want to display bestselling products for time inetrval 7 days. We can set period by day, month and year

```
$bestSellers = $this->_bestSellersCollectionFactory->create()
            ->setPeriod('day');
```

Can we set the date range to show only products from last 7 days like we set in admin [image]